# Javafx Image and Text align on Button

Tags: javafx-2

I created a javafx button and  added image and text.I want text place to top and image place to middle of the javafx button.Is it possible with javafx and how can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

You have to use         `button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);`

[ContentDisplay](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContentDisplay.html)

Comment: That would place the image above the text. I think he wants the image below the text (i.e. `ContentDisplay.Bottom`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CSS for the button. The below example will display the text at the top with the image below (which seems counter-intuitive) for all buttons:

```
.button
{
  -fx-content-display: bottom;
}
```