# Bottom/Top Justify JavaFX Text Content (Label/TextArea)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm looking to top/bottom justify text content in JavaFX.  I feel like this is probably something simple and I've simply run past it in the documentation; apologies if this is the case.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142293/javafx-image-and-text-align-on-button) previous entry, but it does not do what I'm looking for (it is about placing text relative to the graphic).

Here's a quick image (in SceneBuilder) showing what I'm trying to do (top label is top-left justified, bottom label is bottom-left justified).

[image: Example]

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you want to achieve the alignment of the text as depicted by the image on the right side of the arrow. If yes, try the **Alignment** option under the Node section when you select a Label in SceneBuilder?

Comment: Yeah you're right I completely missed that.  My bad; I knew this was something simple I was missing.  If you want to formulate that as an answer, I'll accept it.  I'll write it up tomorrow if it's still unanswered, or if you don't want to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Alignment** option under the *Node* section when you select a Label in SceneBuilder.

[image]

It refers to the [aligmentProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) of the Labeleled :

> Specifies how the text and graphic within the Labeled should be aligned when there is empty space within the Labeled.